# Stack ggplot plots with same axes dimensions

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following hypothetical example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

# df1
descr <- c("aaa","bbb","ccc")
v1 <- c(10,20,30)
df1 <- data.frame(descr,v1)

# df2
descr <- c("aaa","bbb","ccc")
v11 <- c(11111,22222,33333)
df2 <- data.frame(descr,v11)

# plot 1
p01 <- ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = df1, aes(x=descr, y=v1,color=v1), size=5))

# plot 2
p02 <- ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = df2, aes(x=descr, y=v11, color=v11), size=5)

# put them together and save
p_both <- arrangeGrob(p01,p02,nrow=2)
ggsave(file="testSave.png",p_both, width = 10, height = 15, units = "cm")
```

As you can see, the axes don't line up. I am aware that in this particular example I could turn the dfs into long format and use faceting, but that is not the point. 
Is it possible to manually manipulate the axes to make them match up, so that the inner plots are the exact same dimensions?

Thanks!

Comment: Might want to look at `?pretty`: `p01<-p01 + scale_y_continuous(limits = range(pretty(c(df1$v1, df2$v11)))); p02<-p02 + scale_y_continuous(limits = range(pretty(c(df1$v1, df2$v11))))`

Comment: You might be interested in [package cowplot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/plot_grid.html), which makes it pretty straightforward to align axes.

Comment: Ah, I've read about cowplot somewhere yesterday. Will give it a shot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about trying the `patchwork` [package](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork)?

```
library(tidyverse)
# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("thomasp85/patchwork")
library(patchwork)

p01 + p02 + plot_layout(ncol = 1)
```

[image]